# Инвертировать порядок байт

Tags: c++

Как можно изменить порядок байт?

К примеру, мне необходимо работать с файлом, формат которого предписывает хранение данных в **Big-Endian** (такие как *Standard MIDI File*, `.mid`). Напрямую считывать данные я не могу, так как процессора Intel и AMD работают с **Little-Endian**.

Разумеется, есть вариант использования системных функций, но хотелось бы реализовать всё без внешних зависимостей.

Comment: `x =  (x & 0xFF00) >> 8 | (x & 0x00FF) << 8;`

Comment: Неужели стандартные для libc (заголовки в <arpa/inet.h>) функции htonl/ntohl/htons/ntohs не подходят?

Comment: Родной порядок байтов на платформе не должен играть роли, если вы знаете, что файл содержит big-endian: [The byte order fallacy](https://commandcenter.blogspot.ru/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html?m=1)

Comment: [Начиная с C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/byteswap): `#include <bit> ... int t = std::byteswap(1);`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Зависит от размера слова.

- Для двух байт:

  ```
  unsigned short reverse(unsigned short x)
  {
      x = (x & 0xFF) << 8 | (x & 0xFF00) >>  8;
      return x;
  }
  ```
- Для четырёх байт:

  ```
  unsigned int reverse(unsigned int x)
  {
      x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) <<  8 | (x & 0xFF00FF00) >>  8;
      x = (x & 0x0000FFFF) << 16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
      return x;
  }
  ```

***Важное замечание:*** обмен байт безопасно выполнять **только для беззнаковых** типов данных, поскольку знаковые cдвиги являются неопределённым (`<<`), либо неспецифицированным (`>>`) поведением.

Comment: Не работает код

Comment: См. http://ideone.com/iCCfeX

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap_byte(unsigned short *A)
{
    unsigned short temp = *A;
    *((unsigned char*)(A))  = *(((unsigned char*)&temp) + 1);   
    *((unsigned char*)(A)+1) = *((unsigned char*)&temp);       
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на RU Stackoverflow! Постарайтесь давать чуть более развёрнутые объяснения в ответах, чтобы другие пользователи положительно проголосовали за ваш ответ, сообщения можно редактировать кнопкой [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1442671/edit).