# Как правильно положить в буфер число размером более чем 1 байт?

Tags: c++, c

У нас есть массив байтов (допустим, пакет, который мы хотим отправить через сеть) и нам надо в определённое место этого массива положить 32-битное число. Используем порядок байтов little endian (т.е. "обычный").

Напрашиваются два варианта решения:

Первый вариант:

```
inline void put_uint32_le(unsigned char *dst, uint32_t n)
{
    *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *> (dst) = n;
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
inline void put_uint32_le(unsigned char *dst, uint32_t n)
{
    dst[0] = static_cast<unsigned char> (n & 255);
    dst[1] = static_cast<unsigned char> ((n >> 8) & 255);
    dst[2] = static_cast<unsigned char> ((n >> 16) & 255);
    dst[3] = static_cast<unsigned char> (n >> 24);
}
```

Второй вариант более правильный в смысле портируемости и соблюдения стандартов. Проблема в том, что он неэффективный. Говорят, что компилятор умный, что он заметит, что все четыре строчки можно выполнить одной машинной командой, и соптимизирует. Однако, эксперименты показывают, что, например, GCC даже с оптимизацией -O3 по факту этого не делает. Замеры времени показывают, что второй вариант исполняется где-то в полтора раза медленнее, чем первый.

Лично мне неприятно так наплевательски относиться к быстродействию функции, которая у меня будет выполняться тысячу раз в секунду.

Первый вариант работает быстрее, но он работает только если у нас машина с little endian byte order. Но это ладно. Можно сделать так:

```
inline void put_uint32_le(unsigned char *dst, uint32_t n)
{
#ifdef WE_HAVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN_PROCESSOR
    *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *> (dst) = n;
#else
    dst[0] = static_cast<unsigned char> (n & 255);
    dst[1] = static_cast<unsigned char> ((n >> 8) & 255);
    dst[2] = static_cast<unsigned char> ((n >> 16) & 255);
    dst[3] = static_cast<unsigned char> (n >> 24);
#endif
}
```

Хуже другое. Указатель 'dst' может быть невыровненным. В стандарте написано, что выравнивание это "a number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated". Во всём стандарте выравнивание рассматривается именно в таком ключе - ни одно место в стандарте не говорит о том, что к многобайтному числу можно обратиться по невыровненному указателю.

Более того, я и в документации на компилятор ("man gcc", "info gcc") не нахожу, где бы было написано, что компилятор это поддерживает хотя-бы на intel-архитектуре, хотя-бы в качестве расширения стандарта! Хоть-бы #ifdef'ы какие-нибудь сделать, но как именно их сделать, не могу понять!

То есть, то, что я делаю в первом варианте, приводит к undefined behavior. Да, я так уже делал в сотнях программ, и на intel-совместимых процессорах всегда работало. Да, так делаю не только я один. Но никто не обещал, что в следующей версии компилятора это не заглючит, поэтому так делать нельзя.

Более того, если прищуриться, становится видно, что и второй вариант не абсолютно портируемый. Во-первых, у нас может не быть типа uint32_t, поэтому вместо него надо использовать uint_fast32_t. Во-вторых, у нас, теоретически, unsigned char может состоять более чем из восьми битов. Если первая проблема легко решается, то со второй ума не приложу что делать.

Кто что посоветует?

---

VTT:

> Что-то вы напридумывали про длинный ассемблер и укладку в стек...

А если подбавить реализьму?

Попробуйте с нижеследующим кодом. Только обязательно укажите версию GCC не позднее 6.3.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

inline uint16_t get_uint16_le(const unsigned char *src)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t *> (src);
}

inline void put_uint32_le(unsigned char *dst, uint_fast32_t n)
{
    memcpy(dst, &n, 4);
//    *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *> (dst) = n;
}

extern const uint32_t crc32_table[256];

static uint32_t calculate_crc32(const unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
    uint32_t crc = 0;

    while (len--)
    {
        crc ^= crc32_table[*(buf++)];
    }

    return crc;
}

void set_crc32(unsigned char *begin)
{
    size_t sz = 3 + get_uint16_le(begin);
    put_uint32_le(begin + sz, calculate_crc32(begin, sz));
}
```

Comment: Если вы работаете с сетями, что б не воспользоваться стандартными функциями, для того и прилагаемыми - типа [`ntohl`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/htonsman.html) и иже с ними? Уж библиотеки-то для работы с сокетами вроде как портируемы...

Comment: Что-то вы какой-то перверсией занимаетесь, используйте `memcpy`. Если еще надо обеспечивать порядок байт (т.е. это уже сейчас должно корректно работать на не little endian архитектурах), то есть Boost.Endian. А вообще я сильно сомневаюсь, что запись 4 байт является местом критического проседания производительности.

Comment: мне кажется вы хотите объять необъятное. Закрепите требования к своему ПО, чтобы не было теоретического 9-байтового char'a и комбо-архитектуры be/le. Ну или попробуйте перейти от бинарного протокола к строковому, что конечно снизит производительность на порядок, но исключит многие проблемы.

Comment: @Harry Во-первых, вы неправильную функцию указали: ntohl изменяет порядок байтов с big endian на "родной для процессора" (т.е. на intel-совместимых процессорах на little endian). Нам эта функция не нужна, потому что у нас число уже имеет "родной для процессора" порядок байтов. А функция, которая изменяет порядок байтов с "родного для процессора" на little endian... не знаю такой. Подскажите, если знаете.

Comment: @Harry Во-вторых, не все протоколы на свете придуманы лично мной. Я понимаю, что, теоретически, при передаче через TCP/IP положено использовать big endian, но иногда в прикладном протоколе прямо написано, что используется little endian. И я даже не могу сказать, что это неправильно, потому что с 99-процентной вероятностью и с той и с другой стороны будут little-endian-процессоры, и преобразование в big endian и обратно будет ненужной растратой процессорного времени в угоду замшелому стандарту.

Comment: @Harry В третьих и главных, вопрос вообще не про это. Ну, изменили мы порядок байтов или не меняли - без разницы. После этого у нас в руках всё равно 32-битное число. Его надо положить в буфер. Как это сделать?

Comment: @VTT То есть вот так?

#if WE_HAVE_LITTLE_ENDIAN_PROCESSOR
    memcpy(dst, &n, sizeof(uint32_t))
#else
    ...

Да, так можно. Undefined behaviour здесь нет. По производительности, правда, ещё чуть хуже, чем мой второй вариант, потому что глупый компилятор (даже при включенной оптимизации!) кладёт значение 'n' в стек, затем читает из стека, и только потом, наконец, кладёт куда надо.

mov QWORD PTR [rsp + 0x8], rax
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rsp + 0x8]
mov DWORD PTR [rcx + r11*1 + 0x3], eax

Comment: @goldstar_labs Ладно, фиг с ними с 9-байтовыми char'ами. Запрещаем их static_assert'ами. Хотя уже в этом месте немножко обидно - C++ вроде-же кросплатформенный язык - неужели нет кросплатформенного способа положить число в буфер?!

Big endian / little endian нам не страшно, потому что мы можем написать два варианта функции и выбирать их #ifdef'ами.

Но мой вопрос по прежнему остаётся. Как положить число в буфер в порядке little-endian так, чтобы на little-endian-процессоре это происходило оптимальным способом? И при этом чтобы не было нарушения стандарта.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Может, если сам язык такое не поддерживает, то хотя-бы во фреймворках каких-нибудь такие функции есть?

Comment: @goldstar_labs
> Ну или попробуйте перейти от бинарного протокола к
> строковому, что конечно снизит производительность
> на порядок, но исключит многие проблемы.

А вот это мне не нравится. Идя по этому пути мы как-бы говорим: "Мы слишком тупые, чтобы придумать, как положить число в буфер естественным способом, поэтому наши программы будут жрать в 5 раз больше трафика, наши устройства будут просаживать батарейки в 2 раза быстрее и т.д."

Comment: @rod1gin Что-то [вы напридумывали про длинный ассемблер и укладку в стек](https://godbolt.org/g/fExZfm)...

Comment: @VTT Ваша ссылка не работает, но идею я понял. Долго разбирался, почему у Вас работает, а у меня нет. Ответ ниже.

Comment: @rod1gin Ссылка работает...

Comment: @rod1gin, Ну явный баг в оптимизаторе — не первый и не последний... не особо интересно... тем более, что в новых версиях он, очевидно, исправлен...

Comment: @Fat-Zer И всё равно мне предложенный VTT метод не нравится. Если бы он мог привести только к паре лишних машинных команд, это ещё куда ни шло. Но ведь там настоящий вызов функции может подставиться! А функция достаточно тяжёлая и медленная, потому что она рассчитана на оптимальное копирование блоков в мегабайты размером (с учётом того, что копировать лучше машинными словами, а не отдельными байтами, и что блок-источник и блок-приёмник могут быть выровнены по разному). В результате есть риск, что такое решение замедлит программу в тысячи раз, и ещё и не сразу будет понятно, что случилось.

Answer (score 3):

`memcpy` реализован как встроенная в компилятор функция, такие функции называют builtin или intrinsic, таким образом, хоть помещать, хоть дрставать можно через неё. Не следует бояться лишнего копирования в 32битную переменную, такое копировани может быть соптимизировано, то есть memcpy вариант -  это корректная версия первого варианта.

UB первого варианта возникает из-за алиасинга. С этим тоже можно бороться -- компиляторы имеют средства, чтобы сказать, что конкретная переменная может совпадать с другой, например `__attribute__ ((may_alias))`. Но лучше вариант с `memcpy`.

Для смены порядка байт есть инструкции, меняющие их в регистре. Для x86 это BSWAP. Интртнсики `__byteswap_ulong`  или `__builtin_bswap32`. Компилятор вообще обычно в состоянии догадаться вставить эту инструкцию, если написать смену байт на сдвигах. Есть  и инструкция `movbe`, которая меняет байты сразу при доступе к памяти - интринсики `_loadbe_i32`, `_storebe_i32` из `<immintrin.h>`, но это доступно не везде (и потребует некорректного приведения типов, либо `may_alias` атрибута)

Comment: Обычно *"builtin или intrinsic"* все-таки называют функции, встроенные в компилятор и работающие без заголовочных файлов. Еще, на `__attribute__(noalias)` ругается, перепутали с `__attribute__((may_alias))`?

Comment: 1. Не обязательно, например `_loadbe_i32` и прочие в `<immintin.h>` (причём вне зависимости от компилятора, т.к. определны интелом, а не разработчиками компиляторов). 2. да, попутал

Answer (score 0):

Если в первом варианте вы замените присвоение объединением, то вы избежите неопределённости с выравниванием:

```
union
{
 uint32_t   v;
 uint8_t    c[4];
} value;
```

Но если у вас есть четко оговоренный протокол передачи, то нужно ставить каждый байт на своё место, а для этого преобразовывать между [littel-endian и big-endian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600774/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82).

Comment: Делать через union это почти то же, что делать через memcpy. Компилятор не догадается это соптимизировать в одну машинную команду. Эксперимент показывает, что время исполнения в полтора раза больше, чем при записи по невыровненному указателю.

Comment: @rod1gin не корректно сравнивать memcpy и union. при использовании memcpy у Вас проходит копирование , а если использовать union то при присвоении значения uint32_t , вы можете сразу получить доступ к массиву uint8_t

Comment: Ну, получили мы доступ к массиву uint8_t, и что? Дальше его надо скопировать туда, куда нам надо. Сделать это можно тремя способами: а) через memcpy, как и предлагал VTT, б) отдельно по байтику, в) снова прочитать оттуда 32-битное число и положить по невыровненному указателю.

Comment: @rod1gin Какая у Вас общая задача я могу только предпологать. Но при передачи данных очень удобно создавать объединение , структуры и массива. Элементам структуры вы присваиваете значения и сразу передаете массив. На другой стороне вы считали в массив и у элементов структуры есть значения.

Comment: Тогда структура должна быть #pragma packed, иначе в ней будут "дыры" из-за выравнивания, и получится не такой массив, какой нужен. Плохое решение, потому что для мало-мальски сложного протокола такими структурами формат пакета не опишешь. Но Вы натолкнули меня на мысль: очевидно, если архитектура поддерживает #pragma packed, то подразумевается, что доступ по невыровненному указателю на ней возможен.